# Conversão para int com static_cast em c++

Tags: c++, data, time

Fazendo uma pesquisa encontrei algo relacionado a este erro. Tenho o seguinte erro abaixo:

> ERRO: date.cxx: In member function ‘int
>   CurrentDateTime::GetMonth(const string&)’: date.cxx:125:18: error:
>   cannot convert ‘const Month’ to ‘int’ in return

relacionado a:

```
int CurrentDateTime::GetMonth(const std::string& input)
{
    for(const auto& itr : monthinfo) 
    {
      if(itr.first == input)
      return static_cast<std::vector<int>itr.second>;
    }
}
```

onde montinfo vem de:

```
enum class Month
{
  Jan = 1, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
};

// Datastructure for string to num conversion in month(.i.e."Mar" Month to 3)
std::array<std::pair<std::string, Month>, 12> monthinfo = 
{
    std::make_pair(std::string("Jan"), Month::Jan),
    std::make_pair(std::string("Feb"), Month::Feb),
    std::make_pair(std::string("Mar"), Month::Mar),
    std::make_pair(std::string("Apr"), Month::Apr),
    std::make_pair(std::string("May"), Month::May),
    std::make_pair(std::string("Jun"), Month::Jun),
    std::make_pair(std::string("Jul"), Month::Jul),
    std::make_pair(std::string("Aug"), Month::Aug),
    std::make_pair(std::string("Sep"), Month::Sep),
    std::make_pair(std::string("Oct"), Month::Oct),
    std::make_pair(std::string("Nov"), Month::Nov),
    std::make_pair(std::string("Dec"), Month::Dec)
};
```

Li que enum class não converte implicitamente para int por causa de ser proposital, era preciso usar um *static_cast* no *itr.second*.

Eu tentei fazer algo assim seria realmente isso?

```
int CurrentDateTime::GetMonth(const std::string& input)
{
    for(const auto& itr : monthinfo) 
    {
      if(itr.first == input)
      return static_cast<std::vector<int>itr.second>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Algum motivo pra fazer `std::string("Jan")`? O que é isto `std::vector<int>`? De onde surgiu este `.second`? Acho que tem formas melhores de fazer toda esta estrutura, tem estruturas melhores para fazer desta forma também.

Comment: encontrei este código entao resolvi testa-lo, coloquei no pastebin achei o mesmo quando estava pesquisando sobre algumas formas de mecher com vetores de datas e mas ele me retorna este erro e um rapas me disse que eu deveria fazer static_cast para converter enun class em int, mas nem tenho idéia de como fazer isso realmente pastebin.com/MhF0eC71

Comment: @bigown Qual o problema com o `std::string("Jan")`?  Ele está construindo uma string diretamente no construtor do `std::pair<std::string, Month>`. Sendo assim, o `.second` se refere exatamente ao segundo termo deste `pair`, que neste caso é o `Month`. Essa estrutura é perfeitamente válida e muito usada em c++. Tanto é que no c++17 é o padrão para o que eles chamam de [_structured binding_](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf), mas nesse caso, eles usam o `tuple` que é uma generalização do `pair`

Comment: @Amadeus não conhecia isto. Este código é ruim demais, eu jogaria fora e começaria um novo :)

Comment: @bigown Não sei dizer se o código é bom ou não, mas as estruturas usadas são muito boas e é o jeito idiomático de se fazer

Comment: Eu não faria assim em hipótese alguma, isto parece uma cebola. Eu nunca vi códigos assim em C++, menos ainda algo parecido em outras linguagens, por isto acho estranho você dizer isto, o que contradiz sua resposta.

Comment: @bigown Não quero fazer disso uma discussão extensa, mas fiquei curioso, qual parte que contradiz? Também não entendi a parte da 'cebola'. Tá falando do `std::array`, do `enum class` e do `std::pair`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, respondendo diretamente a sua pergunta, o modo correto de usar o `static_cast`, neste caso, é substituir:

```
return static_cast<std::vector<int>itr.second>;
```

por:

```
return static_cast<int>(itr.second);
```

pois você está convertendo um item do `enum class Month` para um inteiro.

Agora, sinceramente, não acho que tenha sentido fazer isso. O `enum class` foi criado exatamente para evitar essas conversões não desejadas. O correto é que na função `GetMonth` ela retorne um `enum class Month`. Ou em outras palavras, que ela tenha a seguinte assinatura:

```
Month GetMonth(const std::string&) const;
```

Agora, se deseja realmente uma conversão para inteiro, use o `enum` padrão (sem o `class`)

Comment: entao eu peguei este código mas tambem nao entendi direito pq o cara que o desenvolveu quis converter para int, pra min o que for mais logico e correto eu só quis saber como consertar o erro dentro deste tipo de conversao..

Comment: Eu sinceramente nao entendi por que razao ele converte no codigo para int, mas adicionei return static_cast<int>(itr.second); da forma como vc disse e gerou este erro abaixo:   /tmp/ccWCXO05.o: In function `CurrentDateTime::CurrentDateTime()':
date.cxx:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `vtable for CurrentDateTime'
/tmp/ccWCXO05.o: In function `main':
date.cxx:(.text+0x8ea): undefined reference to `CurrentDateTime::~CurrentDateTime()'
date.cxx:(.text+0x90e): undefined reference to `CurrentDateTime::~CurrentDateTime()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Aparentemente o autor tinha o código já feito para uma versão mais antiga do c++ e quis atualiza-la para uma versão mais atual, sem testar o código. Esse erro em particular se refere a ausência da definição do destrutor. Basta defini-lo, por exemplo colocando {}

Comment: agora correu bem mas de acordo com o autor original do codigo o programa tem que gerar o seguinte resultado abaixo no dia atual da semana: Output

    Current Day:Tue
    Current Date:4
    Current Month:11
    Current Year:2014
    Current Hour:10
    Current Min:43
    Current Second:35

###################################### portanto ele gerou este: bash-4.4$ ./date

        Current Day....: 
        Current Date...: 0
        Current Month..: 6556000
        Current Year...: 0
        Current Hour...: 0
        Current Min....: 0
        Current Second.: 0

Comment: Bom, agora é com o autor original do programa. A sua questão era sobre como usar o `static_cast` de forma correta nesse caso. Se o programa está funcionando corretamente ou não, é outro problema

Comment: na verdade queria fazer este programa funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Acho que isso é outra pergunta

Comment: pergunta nao é uma afirmação .... nao entendi pq ele nao esta retornando os meses dias hora corretamente atraves do get se agora ta compilando beleza...

Comment: Compilar não quer dizer que vá funcionar. Só quer dizer que do ponto de vista da linguagem, as construções estão corretas. Para saber qual o problema dele, tem que fazer uma análise do que o programa está fazendo. Por isso eu disse que isso é uma outra pergunta. Não está no escopo dessa. Por exemplo, eu não estou com tempo para debugar o programa. Então, não sei dizer o pq ele não está funcionando

Comment: entendi achei que poderia ser resolvido tudo num tópico só...